# MongoDB on Wamp x64 (win x64) = mongo.native_long error

Tags: php, mongodb, 64-bit, wamp

I've a big problem with my development environment.

Context :
My computer : Win 8.1 **x64**
My WampServer install : **x64**
My MongoDB install : **x64** from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

I've installed the php extension from http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo.

My problem is that our production server store some 64 bits INT into the database.

When I try, in my development environment, to access to this data, I've got:

> MongoCursorException
>
> Cannot natively represent the long 1108547148863410176 on this platform

I found on internet that a parameter of mongoDB called "mongo.native_long = 1" is needed to use 64 bits INT on 64 bits architecture.
But when I try to add this param in my "php.ini" file, the server don't start and give me an error like :

> [19-Nov-2014 18:25:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: To prevent data corruption, you are not allowed to turn on the mongo.native_long setting on 32-bit platforms in Unknown on line 0

Does my mongoDB extension DLL is build on 32 Bit or I missed something to do ?

Comment: Then I assume your development environment is a 32bit system. Either both Windows and therefore WAMPServer is 32bit or you have installed the 32bit WAMPServer on a 64bit OS. Remember you cannot install WAMPserver 64bit on a 32 bit OS.

Comment: As i wrote in the start of the thread, my OS is Win 8.1 x64 so i'm on a 64 Bits windows version with a 64 bits version of WampServer :/

Comment: Are you sure. Do this to make sure. Launch command windows, CD into the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` folder, and run `httpd -V`. Look in the output for the line starting `Architecture`.

Comment: I'm sure, herewith a screen of the output of the command in admin mod :
[Screen of my console (imgur link)](http://imgur.com/iiFnCxM)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the same problem right now

Comment: Nope, still no solution..
I installed a virtual machine with Kubuntu 14.4 64bits and it works fine, the "mongo.native_long" parameter is set to 1 and it's work.

I find somewhere that it's a windows problem which can't use 64 bits integers that mongoDB use, so this problem seems to be impossible to resolve on Windows OS...

Answer (score 6):

For me the only thing that worked was:

```
ini_set('mongo.long_as_object', 1);
```

Hope it saves someone's time. It's one of those stupid things that make you wonder: 
*"Why the hell did I become a programmer?"*

**EDIT:** getting **proper** driver from http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo helped me. I've downloaded latest driver. Check your version using phpinfo() command. E.g. for me, on 64-bit Win7 it's:

```
PHP Version 5.5.12
PHP Extension Build:    API20121212,TS,VC11
```

Notice the "TS,VC11" string. It means it's Thread Safe, but your version may not be thread safe (NTS).

So I downloaded 64bit, TS for PHP 5.5. I was dealing with this problem long time and finally, proper driver solved this issue.

Comment: this helped me on lampp in linux environment, tnx.

Comment: Yeah, this is big thing. Glad it helped you, without proper driver working with mongo can be nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

When using a 32 bit apache console(like wampp or xampp) u should add the following to your php.ini file:

```
mongo.long_as_object= 1
```

The above line should convert all longs to object, this way the exception won't occur.

Hope this helps all the 32 bit users that have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with WAMP x64 on Windows X64. My fix was to [update the Mongo library to 1.6.14](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.14/windows)

Answer (score 0):

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35 in php.ini add : mongo.long_as_object = 1

and

C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin  in php.ini add : mongo.long_as_object = 1